# Can sharding speed up insertion performance in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sharding

Referenced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql), the most popular answer does not mention sharding. As far as I know, postgresql will acquire auto-inc lock every time it inserts, so I think sharding can improve insertion performance. Am I right? If sharding can really improve performance, how does it benefit and cost compared other methods?

Comment: What do you mean with "auto-inc lock"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, [auto-inc lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-notes) is a term in mysql.Will postgresql have similiar locking behaviors when inserting records to generate sequence value?

Comment: No, there will be no "select max(...)" for sequences in Postgres. While there is a lock when obtaining a sequence value, I have never seen this to be a bottleneck (but if it does, it can be alleviated by increasing the CACHE size of the sequence)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the explanation, so do you think the insert operations will benefit from sharding?

Answer (score 1):

As has been clarified in the comments, accessing a sequence will not be a bottleneck in PostgreSQL.

If you are faster inserting into a sharded database depends on where the bottleneck is.

If it is disk I/O or CPU on the database, you will probably be faster spreading the workload across several databases (sharding), as long as they have independent storage and network bandwidth is not a bottleneck.

If the bottleneck is on the client side, you probably won't gain much.

Comment: If the bottleneck is I/O wouldn't be adding additional disks to the server (RAID) also be an option (instead of the more complex sharding setup)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I tried to answer the question "can sharding help insertion performance", not "is sharding my best option".